# How come these buttons are not sizing with weights?

Tags: android, android-layout

I think I'm having problems with `layout_weight`. I'm trying to make the fourth button twice the size of the other buttons, but I'm getting the following:

[image]

And my layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="1.0">

    <!--android:background="@drawable/button_image"-->

    <Button android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Are the weights supposed to give what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **force the proportions** as a fraction, make the `layout_width` of the buttons = 0, and the `weightSum` of the Layout that's containing them equal to the sum of their weights, while this last step is not necessary it will be used if there are child views that don't specify their weight, to calculate it from the remainder.

Note that if you don't set them to 0, then the width will be a product of the width resulting of the  `wrap_content` and the `weight` giving you inexact proportions.

---

**The layout:**

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `layout_width` to 0. I'm assuming this is a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientatation.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_weight` works this way:

1. Items are queried for their initial size
2. Available size is divided according to initial sizes
3. If there is any remaining space, it is divided according to weights.

In your case, the `wrap_content` gives an initial size that does not leave any room for step 3. Using a `layout_width` of 0dp, as recommended by android, results in all elements being given only space according to their weight, regardless of their intrinsic size.